# How to remove a row if a value in a column is less than a value or greater than a value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains all numbers. I want to iterate through the columns and if the column fits a particular criteria, ex. it contains the text 'score' then I want to look in that column and if there are any rows that have a value greater than 3 or less than -3, I want the entire row removed.

I'm currently using something like this, but it seems verbose and there are probably pandas methods that will handle this functionality better.

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'T': [1,2,3,4], 'T_score': [4,3,2,1], 'S': [2,3,1,1], 'S_score': [2,4,2,1]})

for _ in df.columns:
    if 'score' in _:
        df = df[df[_] <= 3]
        df = df[df[_] >= -3]
```

I tried something like this

```
df = df[df[_] <= 3 | df[_] >= -3]
```

But that doesn't work and actually throws an error. So I changed it to:

```
df = df[(df[_] <= 3) | (df[_] >= -3)]
```

But this line does nothing.

Comment: Python tip: never use `_` except for a throwaway variable. But in this you use its contents. So rename it e.g. `for col in df.columns:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `&` instead of `|`:

```
df[(df[_] <= 3) & (df[_] >= -3)]
```

or use `between`:

```
df[df[_].between(-3, 3)]
```

---

In your case, you don't need a for loop, instead you can filter the scores column and then compare the entire data frame:

```
scores = df.filter(like='score')

df[((scores >= -3) & (scores <= 3)).all(1)]

   T  T_score  S  S_score
2  3        2  1        2
3  4        1  1        1
```

Comment: For modified version of the answer I posted, +1

Comment: Does this only work if I'm wanting to KEEP the data left over? For example, if I wanted to see which rows are being deleted, I would think I'd be able to just change the >= to < and so on and swap out the & for |, since I would want values less than -3 OR greater than 3. However, when I try this I get an empty dataframe, which obviously isn't the case since this DOES sort out 2 rows.

Comment: If you want the opposite, you can just use `~` to negate: `df[~((scores >= -3) & (scores <= 3)).all(1)]`

Answer (score 0):

Same thing in a different way, you can use `df.filter` to filter out the columns you need, then `apply` with comprehension and `all`, it avoids the need of manual iteration and repeated assignments of the values:

```py
>>> df[df.filter(like='score').apply(lambda x: all(-3<=i<=3 for i in x), axis=1)]

   T  T_score  S  S_score
2  3        2  1        2
3  4        1  1        1
```